# Run parts of a ipython notebook in a loop / with different input parameter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have written a ipython notebook, which analyses a dataset. Now I want to use this code to loop over different datasets.

The code is split into about 50 cells (including comments, markdown explanations,...). Is there a way to run parts of a notebook in a loop or running a whole notebook with different input parameters?

I don't want to merge all cells into one function or download the code as a python script, as I really like to run (and experimenting with) parts of the analysis by executing only certain cells.

Basically its refactoring parts of a script into a function and calling the function in a loop, just that the "parts of the script" are notebook cells.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`papermill.execute_notebook` was designed (by Netflix) to let us run **notebooks as a function** (which aids in code reuse, experiments reproducibility and memory efficiency - it runs notebooks in batch mode unlike standard python REPL):

```
import papermill as pm

pm.execute_notebook(
   'path/to/input.ipynb',
   'path/to/output.ipynb',
   parameters=dict(alpha=0.6, ratio=0.1)
)
```

More info: [docs](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-execute.html) | [example](https://github.com/nteract/papermill/tree/main/binder/cli-simple).

Answer (score 39):

What I usually do in these scenarios is wrap the important cells as functions (you don't have to merge any of them) and have a certain master cell that iterates over a list of parameters and calls these functions. E.g. this is what a "master cell" looks like in one of my notebooks:

```py
import itertools
# parameters
P_peak_all = [100, 200]
idle_ratio_all = [0., 0.3, 0.6]
# iterate through these parameters and call the notebook's logic
for P_peak, idle_ratio in itertools.product(P_peak_all, idle_ratio_all):
    print(P_peak, idle_ratio, P_peak*idle_ratio)
    print('========================')
    m_synth, m_synth_ns = build_synth_measurement(P_peak, idle_ratio)
    compare_measurements(m_synth, m_synth_ns, "Peak pauser", "No scheduler", file_note="-%d-%d" % (P_peak, int(idle_ratio*100)))
```

You can still have some data dragging throughout the notebook (i.e. calling each function at the bottom of the cell with your data) to be able to test stuff live for individual cells. For example some cell might state:

```py
def square(x):
    y = x**2
    return y
square(x) # where x is your data running from the prior cells
```

Which lets you experiment live and still call the generic functionality from the master cell.

I know it's some additional work to refactor your notebook using functions, but I found it actually increases my notebook's readability which is useful when you come back to it after a longer period and it's easier to convert it to a "proper" script or module if necessary.

Comment: So just to clarify, you mean convert the cells to functions? Interesting... +1

Comment: Exactly. Though you maybe don't have to do it for all the cells, but just for the cells that actually modify data that is used afterwards. In some cells you are maybe just doing "one-off" data exploration and visualisation.

Comment: There is also a "cell to function" extension, which can do part of the work. See this example notebook: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/takluyver/cell2function/blob/master/Cell2function%20demo.ipynb

Comment: The bothersome part is I usually have "global" data that passes from cell to next.  This makes function-factoring a PITA.  Thankfully it's only a problem for data that changes values during processing.  Objects whose contents change are also safe, as long as the top-level reference isn't changed.

Comment: it would be cool to have a line magic to make a context from which to run all cells below (possibly in a recursive fashion)

Answer (score 6):

A cheap, but fast trick is to use "run all cells" in a kind of while loop:

[Ipython/Jupyter - can we program a "run all cell above"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267540/ipython-jupyter-can-we-program-a-run-all-cell-above)

change_parameters

***your code***

put this in your last cell:

display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_all_cells()'))

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
    from IPython.display import Javascript
    Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cell_range(5,51)") # 51 is not
```

*Note: Do not use the indices shown beside the cells because `Jupyter.notebook.execute_cell_range` count every single cell including heading and markdown cells. Try to count manually the range of your cells including the markdown cells to give `Jupyter.notebook.execute_cell_range` the correct range.*

Comment: I don't think this `Javascript` can be controlled using a loop.

Answer (score 3):

In case useful... in AWS JupyterLab, i was able to call one notebook from another using the cellmagic `%run` inside a loop, thus calling it multiple times from a control notebook.

I had a list of dates and needed to call the whole notebook for each date in the list, so was like this:

```
for x in date_list:  
    %run "other_notebook_name.ipynb"
```

No need to pass parameters as all code is effectively in the same notebook this way.

May help others as I ended up here looking for an answer this week.
Cheers